# Questions about Data Analysis

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, anova, experiment-design

For my research I'm examining whether applying a certain promotional intervention improves the amount of misshapen products bought. The study contains of two parts. In part 1 Scanner data from supermarkets will be taken collected from each intervention (1,2,3,4). So in the end you end up with 4 counts:

1 - The amount of products bought of normal shape with intervention

2- The amount of products bought of normal shape without intervention

3- The amount of products bought of misshapen products with intervention

4- The amount of products bought of misshapen products without intervention.

And I am interested in measuring whether or not the intervention increased the amounts bought of misshapen products.

What statistical analysis works best here? I have been told by some that ANOVA works fine, but others argue this might not be the correct one since the variabel is count data and counts can't be negative.

In part 2 the same study will be replicated in a different country. It is hypothesized that the results in both countries will be quite similar. How do I conduct this analysis? Should I replicate the analysis as in study 1 and if the same conclusions can be made on those results conclude that the same mechanism applies in both countries?

Comment: *the variable is count data and counts can't be negative* True, but if your counts are quite far from zero and in the same order of magnitude you may not need to worry about the zero boundary or unequal variance. Maybe a histogram of the counts would help

Comment: Just to confirm, are you looking for an increase in the absolute amount of misshapen products bought, or the relative amount compared to normal products?

Comment: I suggest you to edit the title of the question. An informative title will help to attract knowledgeable users to answer your question.

Comment: @AccidentalStatistician Both normally shapen and misshapen products will be counted at all times. Both will be sold during every intervention. 
The intervention will be a poster placed underneath the shelves containing both misshapen and normally shapen products.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested myself in a proper way to analyse this setup so here's my take on it hoping someone will comment on it.

If I understand correctly your data may look like this:

```
    supermarket      shape intervention country count
 1:         sm1     Normal          Yes      UK    46
 2:         sm1     Normal           No      UK    44
 3:         sm1 Misshappen          Yes      UK    31
 4:         sm1 Misshappen           No      UK    18
 5:         sm2     Normal          Yes      UK    43
 6:         sm2     Normal           No      UK    52
 7:         sm2 Misshappen          Yes      UK    28
 8:         sm2 Misshappen           No      UK    12
 9:         sm3     Normal          Yes      UK    63
...
```

Here's a plot for 3 countries, each line is a supermarket:

[image]

In this example, *intervention* has no effect on the *normal* shape but it does increase the count when applied to the *Misshappen* product. Overall, the count of normal product is higher than misshappen's.

R code to reproduce this:

```
library(data.table)
library(modelbased)
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
N <- 5 * 3
dat <- data.table(
    supermarket = rep(paste0('sm', 1:N), each= 4),
    shape = rep(c('Normal', 'Normal', 'Misshappen', 'Misshappen'), N),
    intervention = rep(c('Yes', 'No'), N * 2),
    country = rep(c('UK', 'Italy', 'France'), each= (N / 3) * 4),
    count = rnbinom(n= N * 4, mu= c(40, 40, 25, 5), size= 50)
)
dat[, count := ifelse(country == 'UK', count + rpois(n= (5/3)*4, lambda= 10), count)]
dat[, shape := factor(shape, c('Normal', 'Misshappen'))]

dat[, list(count= mean(count)), by= list(shape, intervention, country)]

gg <- ggplot(data= dat, aes(x= paste(shape, intervention, sep= '\n'), y= count, group= supermarket)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    xlab('Shape | Intervention') +
    facet_wrap(~country, nrow= 1)
```

To analyse the first stage (one country), you could fit a generalised linear model with family distribution Poisson to allow the variance of the counts to increase with their mean and prevent the fit from going into negative values.

We model *count* as a combination of shape, intervention and supermarket and we allow an interaction between shape and intervention; i.e. intervention may have a different effect depending on the *shape* of the product:

```
fit <- glm(count ~ shape * intervention + supermarket, data= dat[country == 'UK'], family= 'poisson')

summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = count ~ shape * intervention + supermarket, family = "poisson", 
    data = dat[country == "UK"])

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.8208  -0.5252  -0.2307   0.3686   1.2273  

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                      3.868955   0.098765  39.173  < 2e-16 ***
shapeMisshappen                 -1.282498   0.134130  -9.562  < 2e-16 ***
interventionYes                  0.003899   0.088302   0.044    0.965    
supermarketsm2                  -0.029199   0.120837  -0.242    0.809    
supermarketsm3                   0.115382   0.116638   0.989    0.323    
supermarketsm4                   0.183520   0.114814   1.598    0.110    
supermarketsm5                   0.049133   0.118506   0.415    0.678    
shapeMisshappen:interventionYes  0.802326   0.167843   4.780 1.75e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 157.7991  on 19  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   8.1755  on 12  degrees of freedom
AIC: 130.79

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

In the table `Coefficients` the `intercept` is the baseline taken to be the log(count) for the *normal* product with no intervention. As expected, there is a significant interaction between shape and intervention (row `shapeMisshappen:interventionYes`). Within normal shape, there is no noticeable difference with or without interventions (row `interventionYes`).

With more countries you could fit a generalised linear mixed model to account for multiple supermarkets within countries:

```
fit <- glmer(count ~ shape * intervention + (1|country/supermarket), data= dat, family= 'poisson')

summary(fit)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: count ~ shape * intervention + (1 | country/supermarket)
   Data: dat

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   410.2    422.8   -199.1    398.2       54 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.11781 -0.66383 -0.02402  0.59340  2.93521 

Random effects:
 Groups              Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 supermarket:country (Intercept) 0.025224 0.15882 
 country             (Intercept) 0.008679 0.09316 
Number of obs: 60, groups:  supermarket:country, 15; country, 3

Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                      3.83237    0.07754  49.426   <2e-16 ***
shapeMisshappen                 -1.72847    0.09692 -17.833   <2e-16 ***
interventionYes                 -0.06454    0.05411  -1.193    0.233    
shapeMisshappen:interventionYes  1.25239    0.11549  10.844   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) shpMss intrvY
shapMsshppn -0.188              
intervntnYs -0.338  0.270       
shpMsshpp:Y  0.158 -0.839 -0.468
```

Again, we see that the interaction term is significant and there is no eveidence of difference between interventions within normal shape.

One may consider using the negative binomial family distirbution instead of the Poisson to allow extra variation between counts in addition to the random sampling.